# Very simple authentication using one-time cookie on nginx

Tags: authentication, cookies, nginx, password-protection, http-authentication

I have a site intended only for private consumption by 3 coders. It's simple HTML served by nginx directly but intended for consumption inside and outside the office.

I want to have a simple password or authentication scheme. I could use HTTP auth but these tend to expire fairly often which makes it a pain for people to use. I'm also nervous it's much easier for someone to sniff than cookies.

So I'm wondering if I could just set a cookie on their browsers in JavaScript with a unique long ID and somehow tell nginx to only accept requests (for a particular subdomain) which has this cookie.

Is this simple enough to do? How do I

1. tell nginx to filter by cookie
2. in the browser, set a cookie that never expires?

Answer (score 27):

There is a really quite simple looking solution that I found from [a blog post by  Christian Stocker](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2017/01/12/no-nginx-basic-auth-with-either-network-or-cookie-set.html). It implements the following rules:

1. If the user is on an internal IP, they are allowed.
2. If the user has a cookie set, they are allowed.
3. If neither matches, the user is presented with http basic authentication, and **if they successfully authenticate a long term cookie is set**

This is really the best of both worlds.

Here's the config:

```
map $cookie_letmein $mysite_hascookie {
  "someRandomValue" "yes";
  default           "no";
}
 
geo $mysite_geo {
  192.168.0.0/24 "yes"; #some network which should have access
  10.10.10.0/24  "yes"; #some other network which should have access
  default        "no";
}
 
 
map $mysite_hascookie$mysite_geo $mysite_authentication{
  "yesyes" "off";  #both cookie and IP are correct  => OK
  "yesno"  "off"; #cookie is ok, but IP not  => OK
  "noyes"  "off";  #cookie is not ok, but IP is ok => OK
  default  "Your credentials please"; #everythingles => NOT OK
}
 
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.example.org;
  location / {
    auth_basic  $mysite_authentication;
    auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd/mysite;
    add_header Set-Cookie "letmein=someRandomValue;max-age=3153600000;path=/"; #set that special cookie, when everything is ok
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Comment: lines 7 and 8 should have semicolons instead of colons

Comment: This is a great approach, but this particular way of doing it has a few small flaws (you can't have per-server cookies, the cookie itself as written isn't suitable as an auth cookie (although it's obviously meant as an example)), and the cookie will never expire if you keep visiting the website (maybe that's a feature?). I've got a slightly polished version of this approach you can find at https://gist.github.com/eatnumber1/92e94086dafc7194077df4a6b45b2b75

Answer (score 15):

To have Nginx filter by a cookie, you could perform some action if the cookie **isn't** present, and then your real action for the 3 people that have access, for example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;  # Use HTTPS to protect the secret
    ...
    if ($http_cookie !~ 'secretvalue') {
        return 401; 
    }
    location / {
       # Auth'd behaviour goes here
    }
}
```

And to set a cookie that never expires, fire up your browser's JavaScript console on a page that's on your server's hostname, and enter:

```
document.cookie = 'cookie=secretvalue;max-age=3153600000;path=/;secure';
```

That's technically not forever, but 100 years ought to do it.  You can also use `expires=` for an absolute date in RFC1123 format if you're so inclined and can easily adjust the `path` if you need to.  This also sets the `secure` flag on the cookie so it will only get sent over HTTPS.

There are also browser add-ons that will allow you to create arbitrary cookies, but all modern browsers have a JavaScript console.

Comment: i think you meant !~

Comment: Good catch, @doronaviguy. Updated the answer!

Comment: If the cookies are sent in plaintext, this leaks the secret value to the public internet, which seems not great. I think using TLS would be sufficient to protect the secret, right? You're also at risk of cross site attacks, right?

Comment: @DanielKing Updated the example to use HTTPS and secure cookies.  In general, it's a cookie so standard cookie handling/protection applies for both network transmission and cross-domain access.  If your pages have an XSS then you're in trouble with DOM-accessible cookies, but with some additional server-side work, you could implement [HttpOnly cookies](https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/).